# SocketException: Software caused connection abort

Tags: android, socketexception

I encountered this exception: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort, who can help me.

```
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(Constant.IP_FLY, Constant.PORT_FLY),5000);
            in = socket.getInputStream();
            out = socket.getOutputStream();
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(out);
            dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(in);

protected byte[] readData = new byte[2048];
dataInputStream.read(readData);
```

After the socket is connected, the dataInputStream.read(readData) is executed cyclically, and an exception is encountered:

```
       System.err: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort
System.err: at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
System.err: at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:114)
System.err: at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
System.err: at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:139)
System.err: at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:103)
System.err: at iot.android.com.iott.connection.TcpConnection.readDataBlock(TcpConnection.java:134)
System.err: at iot.android.com.iott.connection.MAVLinkConnection.run(MAVLinkConnection.java:87)
```

The exception is dataInputStream.read(readData), which is iot.android.com.iott.connection.TcpConnection.readDataBlock(TcpConnection.java:134). Has anyone encountered it, any help will be appreciated!

readDataBlock is executed in the run method, readDataBlock is mainly used to read data:

```
while(connect){ dataInputStream.read(readData);}. //connect true:connect,false:disconnect
```

It seems to be related to mobile phones. My mobile phone Android 8.1.0 will report the above exception, but using the 8.0 mobile phone test is no problem.

Comment: what do you mean "cyclically"? do you invoke connection and read in the loop? show both code for "run" and "readDataBlock"

Comment: readDataBlock is executed in the run method, readDataBlock is mainly used to read data: while(connect){
dataInputStream.read(readData);}. It seems to be related to mobile phones. My mobile phone Android 8.1.0 will report the above exception, but using the 8.0 mobile phone test is no problem.